# How to create this list-containing python dictionary in a more pythonic way?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code to create a dictionary whose elements are lists from another dictionary:

```
olddict={'Fiesta': {'key':'Ford'},'Golf': {'key':'Volkswagen'}, 'Bora': {'key':'Volkswagen'} }
newdict = {}
for key, value in olddict.items():
    newkey = value['key']
    if newkey in newdict:
        newdict[newkey].append(key)
    else:
        newdict[newkey] = [key]
```

The code works fine, but seems utterly non-pythonic. Maybe I am a bit tired, but a one-line solution would be great...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> olddict={'Fiesta': {'key':'Ford'},'Golf': {'key':'Volkswagen'}, 'Bora': {'key':'Volkswagen'} }
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> result = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in olddict.items():
...     result[v['key']].append(k)
...

>>> result
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Ford': ['Fiesta'], 'Volkswagen': ['Golf', 'Bora']})
```

This method initializes an empty list when a new key is found. Essentially getting rid of the `else` part in your code. I am not sure you can combine a `defaultdict` with list comprehension to make it a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby as g
keyfunc = lambda x: olddict[x]['key']
newdict = dict( (k, list(vs)) for k, vs in g(sorted(olddict, key=keyfunc), keyfunc))
```

If you are using Python 2.7 or later, you can also use a dict comprehension

```
newdict = { k: list(vs) for k, vs in g(sorted(olddict, key=keyfunc), keyfunc) }
```